# Jenkins makes github status stuck when PR

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-plugins

I am using Jenkins to build. When I start a PR to a protected branch by an administrator, it always gives github two pending status of context "continuous-integration/jenkins/branch" and "continuous-integration/jenkins/pr-head" and have no detail link to them. It never happens when I make a PR from non-administrator. I don't know what is the reason of it.

[image]

And a github status of context "continuous-integration/jenkins/pr-merge" always work and is related to the running status of my Jenkinsfile. No matter who performs the PR.
[image]

Comment: Might be because only admin has write access to repo?

Comment: The non-admin user also has write permission but not admin.